# Symfony FOSREST API Datetime Error

Tags: php, rest, symfony, datetime, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm using symfony 2.7, I have created the API, When I submit the form(json data) using postman, It is not accepting datetime value.

**Form Builder**

```
->add('letAt','datetime')
```

**Command**

```
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="Please enter let at time.")
     */
    protected $letAt;
```

**Entity**

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $letAt;
```

**Request Json**

```
{
"property_type":
    {
        "marketingTitle": "",
        "letAt": "2018-11-11 10:10:10"
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
"errors": {
        "children": {
            "marketingTitle": {},
            "letAt": {
                "errors": [
                    "This value is not valid."
                ],
                "children": {
                    "date": {
                        "children": {
                            "year": {},
                            "month": {},
                            "day": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "time": {
                        "children": {
                            "hour": {},
                            "minute": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

How can I specify dateTime value with Request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony 2.7 the default `datetime` format is `\DateTimeType::HTML5_FORMAT` and it's value `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`.

You specify your format type like that:

```
->add('letAt','datetime', array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss', 'widget' => 'single_text'))
```

Comment: It's working now...Thank you..Just a typo in your answer, witget=>widget :)

Comment: Sorry for that. Typo fixed :)